# Android: startServiceForResult method

Tags: android

Is there any call in android sort of, **startServiceForResult**, just like we have startActivityForResult?

I have created a service to retrieve data from the web APIs and now I want to populate a **ListView** using that data.

I noticed that using Broadcast Receiver, the only method I have is onReceive, which has void datatype and hence I cannot properly inflate my list with the data I receive.

In case there is no startServiceForResult, will it be valid and would it work properly if I pass a service inside the **startActivityForResult** method call?

Comment: you should bind your activity to the service

Comment: yes, as Tim said, it is called `Context#bindService` or if you want quick, ad hoc solution pass `android.os.ResultReceiver` when calling `Context#startService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Use Broadcasts instead

In your Activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver  BReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //put here whaterver you want your activity to do with the intent received
    }           
};

protected void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
             .registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter("message"));
}

protected void onPause (){
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
             .unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
}
```

In Service

```
private void sendBroadcast (boolean success){
    Intent intent = new Intent ("message"); //put the same message as in the filter you used in the activity when registering the receiver
    intent.putExtra("success", success);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from **Android N**, broadcast mechanism using **LocalBroadcastManager** won't work as expected.

**Register** broadcast using:

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("MY_ACTION"));
```

**Unregister** broadcast using:

```
context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

**Send broadcast** using:

```
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html